# How do you make a "please wait" spinner for Angular http requests (or anything really)?

Tags: angular

I've read a ton of different guides including those on Stack Overflow and they all seem to be referencing a different version or implementation of Angular. I'm using Angular 8 and have the base app and a login component. I'm trying to create a spinner that I can turn on whenever there's slow activity (like HTTP requests).

I put this in my app.component.html:

```
<div id="spinner" *ngIf="spinnerOn" (click)="spinnerOn=false" >
    <div id="spinner_content">
        <h1>Please wait</h1>
        <img src="assets/img/spinner.gif"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to call it in my api.service file which looks like so:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }
    getUserDetails(email, password): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post('http://localhost/api/theapp/login.php', {
            email,
            password
        });
    }
}
```

This will return JSON with errors or a success code, but while the user is waiting, I want to open the spinner. There's advice about directives (which I don't have) and injectors (which didn't work). I thought maybe I could just use the `ngIf` to watch the `showspinner` variable, but it doesn't seem to have global scope and even if it did, how would I access that from inside the service?

Comment: Do you want to display the loading spinner after a certain delay after doing a http-request? Or do you want to display it immediately?

Comment: Immediately and staying open until done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a global sharedService and a variable showSpinner inside the service. Now all we need to do is use this variable to toggle for various http requests.

```
someFun() {
this._sharedService.showSpinner = true;
this._http.get(someUrl).subscribe(res => {

}, err=> {}, () => {
// On Complete
this._sharedService.showSpinner = false;
})
}
```

Now in app.component.html use this variable to display the spinner. *ngIf="sharedService.showSpinner"

Comment: Seems clunky to make a service, include, instantiate, and call it from everywhere that needs it, but it seems to work so problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not bad, but the spinnerOn variable is not in global scope (and should NOT be), but in the controller scope of the component/page where you are using the spinner fragment. So inside your controller, you'd say something like `this.spinnerOn = true;` to turn on the spinner.

I recommend that you make this spinner fragment it's own component and then when you use it in a page, dialog or other context, you can set the value of the spinner in your controller code where you intend to call your service.

You can reference how it was handled in this example for a specific component. It would not be difficult to make this more generic for general usage and the behavior in Angular 8 would not be any different. https://itnext.io/using-angular-6-material-auto-complete-with-async-data-6d89501c4b79